# Block EDT till executorservice completes all task

Tags: java, multithreading, ui-thread

In my application i have two jtextpanes and i have a executorservice instacne which contains few task. I want to assure that all the task in the executorservice instance are completed before executing the FocusListener focusGained method of any jtextpanes. Also i add some more task to the executorservice when focusLost method is called.

Code

```
top.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
{

  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
  {

    if (ecaViewControl.isInitialized())
    {
      stopRecording();
      executor.execute(new Runnable()
      {

        public void run()
        {
          ecaViewControl.save(top);

        }
      });

      executor.execute(new Runnable()
      {
        public void run()
        {
          ecaViewControl.closeDocument();

        }
      });

   }

  }

   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
   {
   //Need to have completed all the task in executor service before EDT executes the code in here

   });

}
```

Comment: So you want to block the UI until all tasks have finished? Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

if you do know the number of tasks to be finished, consider using of [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

so your code might look like:

```
public void run() {
    try {
    // do something here
    } finally {
       latch.countDown()
    }
}
```

then in the code you're waiting for tasks to complete - simply wait for latch:

```
latch.await();
```

or, instead use [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) if you may live without executor.